# How do you remove fonts from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

When I look at the font list in OpenOffice in Ubuntu there are dozens of fonts that all look the same. They are obviously there for various non-latin alphabets but I have not installed those language packs so the fonts all appear as plain sans. It would be nice to get rid of the ones I don't use to shorten the list and make it easier to find the ones I want. It would also speed up the loading time of the word processor. 
I would also like to install a few replacement fonts so that they are available to all users, (ie. not just by putting them in my .fonts folder).

Comment: This question fits better on AskUbuntu, and here's the answer for [deleting fonts in Ubuntu 18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371213/how-to-delete-fonts-in-ubuntu/1107927#1107927).

Answer (score 5):

You can check where the font are located from

```
/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

Common locations for fonts :

1. `/usr/share/fonts`
2. `/usr/local/share/fonts`
3. `~/.fonts`  (if installed for a single user)
4. `~/.local/share/fonts` (if installed via Font Viewer)

And I guess with admin privileges you can delete them.

Comment: They can also be in `~/.fonts` if they are installed for a single user.

Comment: they can also be in `~/.local/share/fonts` if they are installed via Font Viewer

Comment: Thanks @ruuter, this was my answer for POP!_OS 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

I found the 'font-manager' package useful to disable (without removing) these international fonts.  This seems to solely disable the font for the current user, leaving them in the list for other accounts.

To make things easy:

```
sudo aptitude install font-manager
```

Update and additional details for 14.04:

`sudo apt-get install font-manager` works.  Note that as of early 14.04 if you go to Ubuntu Software Center and look up the font-manager package it will give a message about unsolved unmet dependencies due to font-manager requiring lower versions of some dependent packages than the versions installed already in 14.04.  Never fear, just use apt-get instead.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked to remove the font packages. I removed those on Ubuntu 12.04 (aka Precise Pangolin):

```
ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-punjabi-fonts ttf-wqy-microhei
fonts-kacst* fonts-lao fonts-takao-pgothic fonts-tlwg* fonts-nanum
fonts-khmeros-core
```

(this is an updated list from the one I found on [an article about removing non-English fonts](http://marksnotebook.com/ubuntu/removing-non-english-fonts-ubuntu).)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Go to your home folder.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or (Menu → View → Show Hidden Files).
3. Go to `.fonts`.
4. Delete fonts you don't want.
5. Restart your computer.

Done.

Comment: This will work for only user specific fonts, ie, there are fonts  in /usr/local/share/fonts and /usr/share/fonts too.

Comment: I do not have ~/.fonts directory on Ubuntu 14.04